# Soap UI and WS-A options

Tags: wcf, soap, ws-addressing

I'm developing a simple web service using MS Visual Studio 2008, C# and .net 4.  I used the WCF project template, and thru this, I was able to create a site and deploy it to IIS 7.5.  It pretty much has all the default settings that, just that I added a new binding configuration for the wsHttpBinding where "security mode=None".

Using Soap UI 4.0.1, i wanted to test this service, but found that I had to add the endpoint URL again in the WS-A "To:" field.

Is there a way to change the wsdl or endpoint so I dont need to use the WS-A "To:" field in Soap UI? I don't understand why Soap UI requires the endpoint url again in the WS-A "To:" field when I already provide the wsdl to create the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I changed the configuration from wsHttpBinding to basicHttpBinding, then the WS-A field is not required anymore in SoapUI.  However, I still dont know why SoapUI requires the WS-A "To" field for the wsHttpBinding configuration.  Maybe its a bug/"feature" of SoapUI.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is huge! wsHttpBinding is using SOAP 1.2 (vs 1.1), your authentication elements move to WS-* ones, and more. Here's a good example app that breaks it all down: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36396/Difference-between-BasicHttpBinding-and-WsHttpBind